# Problems moving file pointer

Tags: c, file

I am trying to move my file pointer to the end of the current line. I am using the print statement to check if it is at the end of the current line but it is printing at the end of the next line. I have tried ChatGPT but it's solutions did not work. My code is below.

Relevant parts of main:

```c
clearFile("TEMP.yaml");
FILE *yamlFile = fopen("TEMP.yaml", "a");

writeNewVal(yamlFile, "test", "");
writeNewVal(yamlFile, "mess", " test");
printf("%ld \n", ftell(yamlFile));
fseek(yamlFile, 1, SEEK_SET);
moveBelowDown(yamlFile);
```

Relevant Parts of moveBelowDown:

```c
void moveBelowDown(FILE *file)
{
    //* Move fptr to end of current line
    char current;
    while ((current = fgetc(file)) != '\n' && current != EOF)
        ;

    fseek(file, -1, SEEK_CUR);
    fprintf(file, "TEST");
```

Currently the values in the YAML look like this:

```yaml
test: 
mess:  testTEST
```

And I want it to look something like this:

```yaml
test: TEST
mess: test
```

Comment: [Per cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek): "*If the stream is open in text mode, the only supported values for `offset` are zero (which works with any `origin`) and a value returned by an earlier call to `ftell` on a stream associated with the same file (which only works with origin of `SEEK_SET`)... For text streams, the only valid values of `offset` are ​0​ (applicable to any `origin`) and a value returned by an earlier call to `ftell` (only applicable to `SEEK_SET`).*" Since you are opening the file in text mode, the call to `fseek(file, -1, SEEK_CUR);` is not valid...

Comment: ... In any case, what you are attempting to do is not possible, as you can't *insert* new text in the middle of a file while *preserving* its existing text.  Since you are not setting aside any pre-existing space for `TEST` to occupy, even if you could get the file pointer in the correct position, you would just end up overwriting `mess:`, eg: `test: \nmess:  test\n` would become `test: TESTs:  test\n`. To do what you want, you need to write your new text to a completely new file, and then replace the old file with the new file.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by "move[ing] my file pointer to the end of the current line"?  I'm guessing you want to *extend* an existing line.  However, this will only work for the last line, since (even in "append" mode) the write wont "insert" bytes (with shift), it will overwrite.  Your above code is finding the `\n` then seeking one place *before* that.  So the fprintf() is replacing the `\n`.

Comment: _Side note:_ Although pure text chars are unlikely to be 0xFF, to futureproof your code, you want `char current;` --> `int current;` so that a [legitimate] 0xFF is _not_ mistaken for `EOF` (e.g. 0xFFFFFFFF).

Comment: If you want to change a YAML document in a file, you should load it, change the data structure loaded, and then dump the data structure. Your YAML library should take care of any quoting necessary (e.g. if the value for the key `test` would be a string of digits, or the word "True").

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in the posted code:

- `current` must be defined as an `int` to allow for reliable testing of the end of file. `EOF` has a negative value different from all byte values returned by `fgetc()`, but the `char` type cannot handle all possible values returned by `fgetc()`, so either the `char` type is unsigned and never compares to `EOF` or it is signed and `EOF` cannot be distinguished from a legal byte value (of 255 in most architectures).
- the file must be open in binary mode with `"ab"` for `fseek()` to operate correctly with relative offsets.
- you must issue call to `fseek()` when changing from reading to writing (which you do) and back to reading (which you don't)
- seeking back is ineffective for writing to a file open for appending, so the program cannot work in this mode.  You should open the file for read and update ("r+b") or write and update if it does not exist ("w+b").
- you seem to expect `fprintf` to insert its output at the current location in the file: this does not work and there is no way to achieve this in place in an existing file.  You should load the file in memory and write back the modified version, preferably to a different file.